# NIVO SLIDER Trouble

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am having some loading problems with my slider. http://www.novaprogramming.com Sometimes it loads, and sometimes it does not. I really do not know why.

Comment: Please provide a [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/) on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: could you provide your code here, so we find the exact problem or make a Jsfiddle as @bookcasey mentioned.

Comment: why did you down vote my question, i got the right answer i needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your site render like this

```
<img src="nivo/images/02.png" alt="">
```

Try the img tag like this

```
<img src="/nivo/images/02.png" alt="">
```

In your page remove this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#slider').nivoSlider();

});

</script>
```

its not needed

Comment: Also, can you see if it works....I think it did. If it does not, please comment back!!

Comment: @HunterMitchell: checked your site your and found this error in the nivo slider **Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'nivoSlider'** fix this first.

Comment: I do not know how to fix this issue

Comment: it's unable to fetch the method provide the jquery code you used for nivo slider

Comment: i used this guys post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744973/jquery-slider-uncaught-typeerror-object-object-has-no-method-data Now it loads more than what it used to, but sometome it will not, and when i refresh, the image gets smaller than what i set it to. It also gets of centered.